# Most efficient way to add unique ids to deeply nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I need to add ids to an array of objects:
Example:

```
const workouts = [
  { 
    type: "walk"
    areas: [
      {
        location: 'park'
        day: 'Sunday'
      },
      {
        location: 'beach'
        day: 'Monday'
      }
    ],
    exercise: true
  },
  { 
    type: "run"
    areas: [
      {
        location: 'gym'
        day: 'Saturday'
      },
      {
        location: 'track'
        day: 'Sunday'
      }
    ],
    exercise: true
  }
]
```

In this example, I need to add ids to the `workouts` array and the deeply nested `areas` array. 
I came up with this solution mapping through each of the arrays:

```
const idMappings = workouts.map((workout) => {
    const workoutIdMapping = workout.id ? workout : { ...workout, id: uuid.v4() }; // if there is already an id just return the object -- otherwise generate a random id
    const areasIdMapping = workoutIdMapping.areas.map((area) => {
        return area.id ? area : { ...area, id: uuid.v4() }; // if there is already an id just return the object -- otherwise generate a random id
    });
    return { ...workoutIdMapping, areas: areasIdMapping }; // finally return the updated values with ids
});
```

This correctly returns me the following area with ids:

```
const workouts = [
  { 
    id: "0000-0000-4e6b-9f24-f8e1f2402a9b"
    type: "walk"
    areas: [
      {
        id: "0000-1111-4e6b-9f24-f8e1f2402a9b"
        location: 'park'
        day: 'Sunday'
      },
      {
        id: "0000-2222-4e6b-9f24-f8e1f2402a9b"
        location: 'beach'
        day: 'Monday'
      }
    ],
    exercise: true
  },
  { 
    id: "1111-0000-4e6b-9f24-f8e1f2402a9b"
    type: "run"
    areas: [
      {
        id: "1111-1111-4e6b-9f24-f8e1f2402a9b"
        location: 'gym'
        day: 'Saturday'
      },
      {
        id: "1111-2222-4e6b-9f24-f8e1f2402a9b"
        location: 'track'
        day: 'Sunday'
      }
    ],
    exercise: true
  }
]
```

This algorithm worked correctly but is there a more efficient way to solve this problem -- Is mapping multiple times not an efficient way of approaching this problem -- perhaps there are better ES6 functions I can use?

Comment: if this is a working solution, maybe a better place would be https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you, I flagged this question for moderator intervention to be moved to Code Review

Comment: Commas after each object property are necessary to make this syntactically correct right?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use recursion here. Like this:

```
function setIds (arr) {
  arr.forEach(item => {
    item.id = uuid.v4()
    if (item.areas && item.areas.length > 0) {
      setIds(item.areas)
    }
  })
}

setIds(workouts)
```